# Style in HTML not taken into account

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a JS feature to confirm before delete.
My website is done with Foundation 5 and is responsive.

I have a bunch of div aligned in the grid and some have a delete button. I would like to add a confirm box before deleting the content.
I would like this box to cover the div that has the content. I use JS to get the width and height of the content div (since it's responsive, the size is not the same in desktop, mobile and tablet).
Then I create the confirm box and put the width and height in the html directly.
It seems to work but they are not taken into account, not at all. The confirm box has the size like I did nothing...

HTML:

```
<div class="article-item article-item-drafts item-with-delete">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-2 medium-2 small-2 columns"><img class="image-50" alt="W3 3, Le calice jusqu'à la lie" src="/img/livres/w3-3-le-calice-jusqu-a-la-lie@2x.png"></div>
        <div class="large-10 medium-10 small-10 columns">
            <p class="bookDraftTitle">W3 3, Le calice jusqu'à la lie</p>
            <p class="text-right bookDraftInfo">Modifiée le 29 mars 2016</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
            <hr>
            <p class="text-center regular">Brouillon</p>
            <p class="text-center bookDraftAction"><a title="Modifier" href="/mes-contributions/gerer-mes-critiques/modifier-857.html"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Modifier</a>
    &nbsp;-&nbsp;<a class="delete-content" title="Supprimer" href="/mes-contributions/gerer-mes-critiques/supprimer-857.html"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Supprimer</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.delete-content').click(function() {
    $articleItemLink = this.href;
    $articleItemDraft = $(this).closest('.item-with-delete');
    $articleItemDraftWidth = $articleItemDraft.width() + 20;
    $articleItemDraftHeight = $articleItemDraft.height() + 20;
    $articleItemDraftLink = $(this).closest('.item-with-delete');
    $articleItemDraft.css('position', 'relative')
    $articleItemDraft.append('<div class="item-with-delete-overlay" width="'+$articleItemDraftWidth+'px" height="'+$articleItemDraftHeight+'px">\n\
        <p>Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet élément ?</p>\n\
        <p class="callToAction"><a href="'+ $articleItemLink +'" class="item-with-delete-overlay-yes">Oui</a><a class="item-with-delete-overlay-no">Non</a></p>\n\
        </div>');
    $('.item-with-delete-overlay-no').click(function() {
        $('.item-with-delete-overlay').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('.item-with-delete-overlay-yes').click(function() {
        return true;
    });

    return false;
});
```

Here's an image of the issue:
[image: Error]

It looks like the width works but that's not true.

Any idea how to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please create a working demo? preferably into a stack snippet or jsfiddle. BTW have you tried setting `box-sizing` or checking jQuery's `outerHeight()` and `outerWidth()` instead of `height()` and `width()`?

Comment: You use the style attribute to directly style elements. Your height/width attributes do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue adding the position:absolute, top and left right inside the HTML instead of the CSS.